# The IF statement got it wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, or-operator

Hey I'm a beginner at javascript, and I've come across this issue. It seems like the IF statement recognizes the variable as something it isn't. I think it has something to do with the OR operator?

```
let variabel = `a variable with random value`;

if (variabel === `a` || `b`){
    console.log(`the variable is the same as a or b`)
} else {
    console.log(`not the same`)
}
```

So it does say `the variable is the same as a or b` in the console. So the if statement is true? But it isn't?

Comment: Your if statement is testing whether `variable === 'a'` OR _"b" is true_. Because "b" is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), the condition evaluates to true.

Comment: Your expression is evaluated as ```(variabel === `a`) || (`b`)```.

Comment: Keeping in mind that the template literals aren't getting you anything in this use case.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax is:

```js
let variabel = `a variable with random value`;

if (variabel === `a` || variabel === `b`){
    console.log(`the variable is the same as a or b`)
} else {
    console.log(`not the same`)
}
```

Comment: welp, rookie mistakes. I feel like I will be making those more haha

Answer (score 0):

Correct use of `OR` is this way

```
let variabel = `a variable with random value`;

if (variabel === `a` || variabel === `b`){
    console.log(`the variable is the same as a or b`)
} else {
    console.log(`not the same`)
}
```